# Regex match the first line after blank line

Tags: python, regex

I want to check the first line after `blank line` I tried with `^$.*` but not working,

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS Message Log
Message Log

Message Log
not empty line
```

the desired output :
`["YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS Message Log","Message Log"]`

Comment: `I want to check the first line after blank line` ... your expected output does not match this request.  Please edit and fix your question.

Comment: You mean change the title?

Comment: No, *I want to check the first line after blank line* implies that the expected result should be `"Message Log"` when using your data (there is no blank line prior to `"YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS Message Log"`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
import re


pattern = re.compile("(?:^|\n\n)(.*)")
pattern.findall(data)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS Message Log', 'Message Log']
```

To test it, I have saved these lines in a file:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS Message Log
Message Log

Message Log
not empty line
```

read the content in `data` and applied the pattern to it.

Comment: I got `['', 'Message Log']`

Comment: Replace `.*` with `.+` so blank lines are not matched.